# Is Behaviour supported on wpf in 3.5? I cannot see System.Windows.Interactivity in VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior

Is Behaviour supported on wpf in 3.5? I cannot see System.Windows.Interactivity in VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behaviours are part of Blend. They renamed the assembly from Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity to System.Windows.Interactivity because it may be added in a future version of the framework, but that's not the case currently. If you want to use behaviors, redistribute the assembly along with your application.